# Summarising long form data set and displaying in a table

Tags: r, gt

Good day all!

Excuse my title being vague but I am having trouble expressing my desire concisely and, consequently, I don't know the proper terms to google.

I have data like this:

```
df <- tibble(
  PersonID = c(1:10),
  Location = c("Atlanta", "Chicago", "Denver", "Baltimore", "Baltimore", "Atlanta", "Denver", "Chicago", "Atlanta", "Baltimore"),
  Success = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
  )
```

What I want, eventually, should be simple. I want the Locations to be columns and one row underneath with the number of events per Location and the proportion of successful attempts.

```
| Atlanta | Baltimore | Chicago | Denver |

| --------| --------- | ------- | ------ |

| 2 (66.7)| 1 (33.3)  | 2 (100) | 0 (0)  |
```

I know a bit of `library(gt)` but to no avail. I have no preferences towards any package so feel free to suggest any solution.

Thank you all very much!

P. S.: I would like to tip you a coffee :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to format the data in desired format using `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

We create a summarising function (`sum_and_prop`) and apply it to every `Location` while getting the data in wide format using `pivot_wider`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

sum_and_prop <- function(x) {
  sprintf('%d (%.1f)', sum(x), mean(x) * 100)
}

result <- df %>%
  arrange(Location) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = -PersonID, names_from = Location, 
              values_from = Success, values_fn = sum_and_prop)
result

#  Atlanta  Baltimore Chicago   Denver 
#  <chr>    <chr>     <chr>     <chr>  
#1 2 (66.7) 1 (33.3)  2 (100.0) 0 (0.0)
```

The output of this can be passed to `gt` or any other library of your choice.

```
gt::gt(result)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, not the first time I'm buying you a drink … .-)

Comment: Oh, one little extra request. Is there a way to either write in to Cell or by using a table-package you know to write the number of attempts into the Location name? Like "Atlanta (N=3)", "Chicago (N=2)" …?

Comment: You can use `length` for that. `sum_and_prop <- function(x) sprintf('%d (%.1f, N = %d)', sum(x), mean(x) * 100, length(x))` or only with `N` - `sum_and_prop <- function(x) sprintf('%d (N = %d)', sum(x), length(x))` @KlausPeter

Answer (score 0):

They are multiple possibilities depending on the package you use for export (gt, flextable, *etc.*). Do you need MS Office export ? HTML ? PDF ? Is it to be used inside a Quarto/Rmarkdown document ? These questions might help to find the package that better suits your needs with parameters such as decimal and thousand separators,text align...

Here is some code to get the expected output in the console:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
  PersonID = c(1:10),
  Location = c("Atlanta", "Chicago", "Denver", "Baltimore", "Baltimore", "Atlanta", "Denver", "Chicago", "Atlanta", "Baltimore"),
  Success = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
)

df %>% 
  group_by(Location) %>% 
  summarise(n = n(),
            success_rate = sum(Success)/n) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(label = paste(n, paste0("(", round(success_rate, 2), ")"))) %>% 
  select(Location, label) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Location, values_from = label)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 4
#>   Atlanta  Baltimore Chicago Denver
#>   <chr>    <chr>     <chr>   <chr> 
#> 1 3 (0.67) 3 (0.33)  2 (1)   2 (0)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>